# How to make a matrix with a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I build such a matrix using a loop?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this, even without a loop via numpy.

```
import numpy as np
np.eye(10, k=0, dtype=int) *-1
```

Comment: @Synthase i think what the OP really meant is how to not hard-code the matrix. Why would anyone prefer a loop over a simple one-liner?

Comment: @Synthase I had the same hypothesis regarding the question as Tomerikoo, because I often saw questions where the person asking them, wasn't aware of even cleaner solutions. Therefore you first comment is of course right, but also from a pedagogic point of view, if in the future other readers have a smilar question they might come here, some really want a loop, some a one liner. In my oppinion both should know that there are alternatives, the one liner and your actual for loop.

Comment: Sure, that's why I added my own one-liner ;). But still using for loops! I take note, however :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a symmetrical 2D array using `for` loops. The classical approach would be:

```
import numpy as np

ax0 = 5
ax1 = ax0

l = []

for i in range(ax0):
    l.append([])
    for j in range(ax1):
        if i != j:
            l[i].append(0)
        else:
            l[i].append(-1)

print (np.array(l))
```

Output:

```
[[-1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -1]]
```

You can make a much more compact code by using list comprehension:

```
print (np.array([ [ 0 if i != j else -1 for j in range(ax1) ] for i in range(ax0) ]))
```

This output the same and is also using for loops and conditional assignment for the diagonal.